# Spam Click A Username-Change Button on a Website

Tags: button, web, click, spam

I want to create a program that automatically spam clicks a button that changes my Minecraft username. The button is on https://account.mojang.com/

Also, how would I make the program run at a preset time?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
document.querySelector('.huge.button').click()
```

I'm guessing you are new to javascript which is great! The document part says that the html element we are looking for is in the document. The querySelector() part finds the correct element. Then .click() clicks it.

To make the JavaScript code run, you can either go to the developer console or in the url bar type javascript:codehere

Comment: So I tried going to the console and typing "javascript:document.querySelector('changeButton').click()"

'changeButton' is the name of the button

However, I keep on getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null at <anonymous>:1:50

Comment: That must be the wrong element. I'm not sure that is how query selector works. Go the the element right click on it, and click copy query selector